# check whether anchor have href test case using protractor

Tags: protractor

1)how to test whether anchor tag have a href with protractor.Like i have to test if all the links in header  and footer are working using protractor testcase.2)and a div contain an input button testcase

Comment: Could you please explain your question more clearly and provide some example code?

Comment: Can you provide an example of the HTML?

Answer (score -1):

For checking if all links have hrefs, you can find all links and then check their href attribute:

```
it('all a links have hrefs', function() {
  element.all(by.xpath('//a')).then(function(links) {
    for (var i = 0; i < links.length; i++) {
      expect(links[i].getAttribute('href')).not.toBeNull();
    }
  });
});
```

For checking if a div contains an input button, you can search by xpath under the div:

```
it('button found in a div', function() {
  var div = element(by.id('somediv'));
  expect(div.isElementPresent(by.xpath('//input[@type="button"]'))).toBeTruthy();
});
```